# Deleting based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with multiple columns, like

ID number, a snapshotdate, a month name, and a source. (and quite a few more columns)

I want to delete the rows where the source is (V2) but only
If for a certain ID number, date and month that there is BOTH of values (V1) (V2) in the source

The Source can also contain other values fyi (V3, V4 etc.)

I can't seem to find a way to code this inside a stored procedure in SSMS, anyone who can help?

I basically want to delete every row with source V2, if for each unique
Key C, Key F and Key G (combined) exist both V1 and V2.
[Imgur Photo](https://imgur.com/a/Y7eqXqi)

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and desired output ?

Comment: See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Added a imgur foto of the data setup. I basically want to remove rows where the is both a V1 and V2 source for a specific Key C, Key F and key G

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN for multiple values of sources like V2, V3, and V4. A sample data might be helpful but you could write a query like;

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE 
source IN ('V2', 'V3', 'V4') 
AND ID = 10 
AND Date = '2021-10-10';
```

Comment: This would delete my V2 sources even if there is no V1 source. I only want to delete V2 sources if there is also V1 for a specific id, date and month

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to do an IF EXISTS THEN DELETE query. There's another way of going about this, which is shown below. To explain, you'll just create a table of entries dynamically which match all your conditions and perform the deletion if the join succeeds.

```
DELETE          tab
FROM            TABLE tab
INNER JOIN      (SELECT         *
                 FROM           TABLE tab
                 WHERE          tab.ID = Your_Number
                 AND            tab.SnapshotDate = Your_Date
                 AND            tab.MonthName = Your_Month_Name
                 AND            Source IN (V1, V2)
                ) joinCondition ON tab.ID = joinCondition.ID
WHERE           tab.ID = Your_Number
AND             tab.SnapshotDate = Your_Date
AND             tab.MonthName = Your_Month_Name
AND             Source = V2
```

You can see this in action with the fiddles below :

1. Before the delete statement : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f64bb/3
2. After the delete statement : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f64bb/5

Comment: Doesnt appear to be working / allowing me to join right after a delete from command? It's a query inside an Azure SQL Database, writing T-SQL i think?

Comment: @AlexanderMilland It was a typo. Should've been `Delete` **tableAlias** `from table tableAlias` instead of `Delete from table tableAlias`. Have added an example so you can have a look at it in action.

Comment: Got it to work with the new tableAlias, sweet.